# How to access Swift files from main target in test target

Tags: testing, swift, xcode6

I'm implementing some tests and I need to access the source files from my main target.
Do I need to add all required files in "Compile Sources" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to add them in "Compile Sources". Alternatively you can select file in "Project Navigator" and change target membership in "Utility -> File Inspector" pane on right side of Xcode window.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `@testable import ${app target name}` in your test file written in swift.